# Unit testing controllers (Jasmine/Angular) that run code when the page loads

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine, onload

I'm attempting to unit test some angular js controllers that I have written within the jasmine testing framework. I've got everything set up so that I am able to create instances of my controller, and pass in mock services.

However, I've got a few lines of code that run when the page loads.

```
$scope.tags = [];
$scope.noData = false;

$scope.generateSearchResults = function(input){
    searchAPI.executeSearch(input).then(function(res){
        $scope.tags = res.data;
    });
};

//does some post processing on tags
$scope.checkNumberOfResults = function(){
    if($scope.tags.length < 1){
        $scope.noData = true;
    }
}

//this is the code that runs when the page loads.. normally I want this behavior,
//but for my jasmine unit tests, I don't want the controller running any code on
//instantiation
$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    $scope.searchQuery = $routeParams.query; //grabs from the url
    $scope.generateSearchResults($scope.searchQuery){
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.checkNumberOfResults();
    });
});
```

So if you can tell, when the page loads I want to grab a query string from the url and then display search results. The thing is, I don't want this code to be run while testing, at least not for my unit tests. Maybe when I do some integration tests I will want to be able to simulate a page load, but for now, I want to unit test some of my other functions in the controller without necessarily requiring a call to the search API service..

Does that make sense? Does anyone have any advice for where to go on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of watching for the `$viewContentLoaded` event you could inject the `searchQuery` into your controller by using resolve of [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) or [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki). This allows you to mock the `searchQuery` in your tests and be independent of page loading and `$routeParams`

```
// code for ngRouter
...
controller: 'MyCtrl',
resolve: {
   searchQuery: function ($route) {
     // grabs search query from URL
     return $route.current.params.query;
   }
}
```

Then inject `searchQuery` into your controller:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, searchQuery) {

  $scope.$watch('searchQuery', function(newValue){
    // ignore undefined etc.      
    if (!newValue) { return; }
    $scope.generateSearchResults($scope.searchQuery){
    .then(function(res){
      $scope.checkNumberOfResults();
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: I've got a file app.js, that essentially links up the modules and determines which templates get which controllers. Would the ng router code go in there?

Comment: I like this solution for the time being, basically my results update whenever the searchQuery does, which is pretty cool

Comment: Yes, use the config method of the angular module to link templates and controllers.

`angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/route', {
      templateUrl: 'my-tpl.html,
      controller: 'MyCtrl',
      resolve: { /*resolve*/ }
    });

});`